# I want to blink the LED's in reverse order

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, pic

I want to reverse the code as it complete first time. For example pin 1-pin 2-pin 3-pin 4 (it's complete) now it should run as pin 4-pin 3-pin 2-pin 1.

I wrote this code but it's not working in reverse order. Please guide me in this way.

```
#include<htc.h>
__CONFIG(1,OSCSDIS & HSPLL); 
__CONFIG(2,BORDIS & PWRTDIS &WDTDIS);
__CONFIG(3,CCP2RC1); 
__CONFIG(4,LVPDIS & STVREN);
__CONFIG(5,UNPROTECT); 
__CONFIG(6,WRTEN); 
__CONFIG(7,TRU);

define _XTAL_FREQ 40000000

void delay_sec(unsigned char seconds) // This function provides delay in terms of seconds
{ 
    unsigned char i,j;
    for(i=0;i<seconds;i++)
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
            __delay_ms(10);
} 

void led_display(char a) 
{ 
    switch(a)
    { 
        case 0: PORTB=0x01;PORTD=0x08; break;
        case 1: PORTB=0x02;PORTD=0x04; break;
        case 2: PORTB=0x04;PORTD=0x02; break; 
        case 3: PORTB=0x08;PORTD=0x01; break; 
    }
} 

void main() 
{
    TRISB=0x00; TRISD=0x00; char a,b;
    while(1) {
        led_display(a);
        a++; 
        delay_sec(1); 
        if(a==4) { 
            a--; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code so it's readable.

Comment: @RedX I suspect it won't compile either: `define _XTAL_FREQ 40000000`

Comment: I know this is a different problem, but why are you using two loops and a 10-msec delay to sleep for a second? Wouldn't it be better to call sleep(3C) on Linux or Sleep on Windows?

Comment: You need to keep track of which direction you're going. For example, you could set `b` to `1` to go one direction, and set `b` to `-1` to go the other direction. Then update `a` with `a += b;`.

Comment: Please, don't cross-post. (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136591/i-want-to-blink-the-leds-in-reverse-order) With only 1/2 an hour between each of the two posts, one could be forgiven for thinking you impatient..

Comment: @user2034574 Because he is using a microcontroller... An 8-bit PIC, which has a CPU architecture from the 70s and likely just a few bytes of RAM, doesn't come with Windows 8 pre-installed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing that, you have to remember in which order you are running (reverse or not). So you will have a variable indicating if the order is reverse or not, and change it when you reach the extremities of your counter (0 and 3)

And you can optimize the code with using 1 and -1 for the variable which remembers order and adding it to a.

Your code will seem like this in your main :

```
int reverse = 1, 
char a = 0;

while(1)
{
led_display(a);
delay_sec(1);

if(a==3)
    {
    reverse=-1;
    }
if(a==0)
    {
    reverse=1;
    }

    a+=reverse;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: now i want to turn on led in a sequence i.e
1 3 2 4

now what should i do???

Comment: there's no logic way to do that... The best thing you have to do is to create a kind of lookup table by changing the correspondance between a and the active LED. You change that in your "switch case", in example by swapping the action of the cases 2 and 3.